# Excel: Catagorizing data while categories are defined by substrings

Tags: excel, substring

For a project I have acquired my data in a rather specific way and due to its large size. I will need an automatic method to analyze it. I have got an excel file containing a two-column table like the following:

```
"Fruit" "Apple Peer Banana Mango"

"Vegetables" "Tomato Carrot Lettuce"

"Meat" "Chicken Fish"
```

The first column is meant as categories, and the options in the second column are simply separated by spaces.
A second sheet contains a list of all values, where every value needs to be categorized. As for the example, if we have 4 rows (without the ""):

```
"Carrot"

"Banana"

"Lettuce"

"Fish"
```

The second column should add their categories:

```
"Carrot" "Vegetables"

"Banana" "Fruit"

"Lettuce" "Vegetables"

"Fish" "Meat"
```

Is there an automatic way to do this? In my data all values are very distinct, so I don't have to cope with say "tomatosoup" in the example, or anything that could cause problems with substrings.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could [import the text data](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) and delimit upon space character, then you could do a find and replace to remove all quote characters, then you could do a [data transpose](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-ed1215f5-59af-47e6-953b-0b513b094dc2) to get the columns setup correctly, then you could use a lookup formula for the last part.

Comment: Thx for your responses. A collegue helped me out. He changed the category names to numbers, separated the substrings into columns and pulled the following formula on the to-be-catagorized sheet (having the same number of columns as the biggest category): =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2;Sheet2!B:BI;E$1;FALSE);"") finally he summed the rows =SUM(E2:BI2)